# How to delete the void pointer in destructor?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class like this:

```
class IncomingNetworkEvent {
private:
    IncomingNetworkEventForGame event;
    void* item;
public:
    IncomingNetworkEvent();
    ~IncomingNetworkEvent();
    IncomingNetworkEventForGame getEvent();
    void setEvent(IncomingNetworkEventForGame event);
    void* getItem();
    void setItem (void* item);
};
```

And a member variable in other class

```
vector<IncomingNetworkEvent> m_incomingNetworkArray;
```

When an event comes I create the `IncomingNetworkEvent` and `setItem` (item may be of different type based on event after type casting to `void*`).After creating the `IncomingNetworkEvent` I put it on the `m_incomingNetworkArray`.

So there is a case when I want to clear the `m_incomingNetworkArray.clear()`. It will call the destructor of `IncomingNetworkEvent` but I have to delete item which is `void`. So to delete it I have to typecast back to proper type.
One solution will be in destructor I typecase the item according to event (I know which event contains which type). But it will create lot of switch case in the destructor.

So I wanted a solution like this:

```
template <class T>
class IncomingNetworkEvent {
private:
    IncomingNetworkEventForGame event;
    T* item;
public:
    IncomingNetworkEvent();
    ~IncomingNetworkEvent();
    IncomingNetworkEventForGame getEvent();
    void setEvent(IncomingNetworkEventForGame event);
    T* getItem();
    void setItem (T* item);
};
```

So I can delete item in the destructor without typecasting. But the problem is I cannot declare incoming network array like:

```
vector<IncomingNetworkEvent> m_incomingNetworkArray;
```

I have to declare it as:

```
vector<IncomingNetworkEvent<someType>> m_incomingNetworkArray;
```

But this will not solve my problem as `m_incomingNetworkArray` will can process only `IncomingNetworkEvent` of one type.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Can you make `item` point to a base class, and then all the actual items are created derived from that base class?

Comment: ***i know which event contains which type***. So why is item not part of event itself?

Comment: I have lots of event and half of them doesnt contain any item.So if i keep item to be part of event(which is enum) i have to create lots of classes.I think Martin Boner solution is good.

Comment: So you set item depending upon `IncomingNetworkEvent`? So I guess there might be a if-else or switch construct which selects a type of item from among many and sets it.

Comment: Yes as i get the item from server i set the IncomingNetworkEvent and push to the m_incomingNetworkArray.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `ItemBase` class from which all items are created. This class will have a virtual destructor.

Now instead of passing your Item as `void *`, let it downcast to `ItemBase *` and you would be able to `delete` it as long as the type is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
class IncomingNetworkEvent final {
private:
    // ...

    std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> item{nullptr, [](void*){}};

public:
    // ...

    void* getItem() { return item.get(); }

    template<typename T>
    void setItem (T* ptr) {
        item = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>{ptr, [](void *ptr){ delete static_cast<T*>(ptr); }};
    }
};
```

I assumed that the object takes the ownership of `ptr`, for it is also the one demanded to delete it.
The basic idea is that you are still erasing the original type (thus using `void*`), but you set a proper destructor when you construct the internal item.

To use it, you can simply write:

```
IncomingNetworkEvent ev;
ev.setItem(new int);
```

Deduction will do the rest.

If you can't use `std:: unique_ptr` and lambdas for some reason, you can achieve the same result by means of a template function or static member template function.

Comment: Previously i cant understand your code specially  std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> item{nullptr, [](void*){}}; , the second argument but now i got it.Thanx

Comment: @user1438832 Do you want me to add more details to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a non-template base and a template derived class. The events vector then holds pointers to the base class.

I also suggest that you use `std::unique_ptr` to designate ownership throughout.

```
class IncomingNetworkEventBase {
private:
    IncomingNetworkEventForGame event;
public:
    virtual ~IncomingNetworkEventBase() = default;
    IncomingNetworkEventForGame getEvent();
    void setEvent(IncomingNetworkEventForGame event);
};

template <class T>
class IncomingNetworkEvent : public IncomingNetworkEventBase{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_item;
public:
    T* getItem() { return m_item.get(); }
    void setItem (std::unique_ptr<T> item) { m_item = std::move(item); }
};

vector<std::unique_ptr<IncomingNetworkEventBase>> m_incomingNetworkArray;
```